# Kendo Treeview and read url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-treeview

Problem: 
having issues binding Kendo Treeview to Remote Data Source using HierarchicalDataSource

> Object Doesn't support property or method 'level'

I think the problem has to do with my json response as it is encoded with a whole bunch of scape characters; I don't know how I can force Transport.Read.Url to use $.parseJson(data). All I can do is feed it the url to my action in the controller; but the result from my controller is pure json with a lot of scape characters... please help

Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult TreeItems(int? jobId, int? parentJobId)
{
    var data = new List<object>()
    {
        new
        {
            NodeId = 1,
            caption = "test1",
            hasChildren = true,
            items = new List<object>()
            {
                new
                {
                    NodeId = 2,
                    caption = "test2",
                    hasChildren = false,
                    parentId = "1"
                },
                new
                {
                    NodeId = 3,
                    caption = "test3",
                    hasChildren = false,
                    parentId = "1"
                },
            }
        }
    };
    return Json(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var ds1 = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource(
{
    transport:
    {
        read:
        {
            url: urlToTreeItems
            , dataType: "json"
            , type: "POST"
        },
        schema:
        {
            model:
            {
                id: "id",
                text: "caption",
                hasChildren: "hasChildren"
            }
        },
    }
});
var tv = $("#test").kendoTreeView(
{
    dataSource: ds1
}).data("kendoTreeView");
```

Response:

```
"[{\"NodeId\":1,\"caption\":\"test1\",\"hasChildren\":true,\"items\":[{\"NodeId\":2,\"caption\":\"test2\",\"hasChildren\":false,\"parentId\":\"1\"},{\"NodeId\":3,\"caption\":\"test3\",\"hasChildren\":false,\"parentId\":\"1\"}]}]"
```

//EDITED: Also wanted to mention I have tried the following; it simply displays "undefined" for the node-texts and the tree nodes don't expand

```
var ds2 = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource(
{
    transport:
    {
        read: function (options)
        {
            Ajax(urlToTreeItems, false, null, "POST", null, "application/json; charset=utf-8", "json",
            function (result)
            {
                var jResult = $.parseJSON(result);
                options.success(jResult);
            });
        },
        schema:
        {
            model:
            {
                id: "NodeId",
                text: "caption",
                hasChildren: "hasChildren"
            }
        },
    }
});

var tv = $("#test").kendoTreeView(
{
    dataSource: ds2
}).data("kendoTreeView");
```

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
 schema:
    {
        model:
        {
            id: "NodeId",
            children: "items"
            hasChildren: "hasChildren"
        }
    }
```

Comment: @DotNet98 the property children allow expandable items